# Can I place a restrictive relative clause before a noun that it modifies?

Tags: relative-clauses, syntax

Can I place a restrictive relative clause before a noun that it modifies?

For example, can I re-write the following sentence

> This is an adverb that is **usually emphasized by being placed at the
>   beginning of a sentence**; it is very common in this language.

this way

> This **usually emphasized by being placed at the beginning of a
>   sentence** adverb is very common in this language.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most speakers would consider it strange and unnatural.   Now and then I have heard native speakers say this sort of thing but not speakers who were well educated.

A painted black window is opaque. <sup>No</sup>

A window painted black is opaque. <sup>Yes</sup>

A closed tight window shouldn't leak. <sup>No</sup>

A window closed tight shouldn't leak. <sup>Yes</sup>

A taken to the cleaners person is one who has been cheated or scammed. <sup>No</sup>

A person taken to the cleaners is one who has been cheated or scammed. <sup>Yes</sup>

These are "post-nominal" modifiers.

But you could do this:

Closed tight, a window shouldn't leak.

Painted black, a window is opaque.

Taken to the cleaners, a person has been cheated or scammed.